# Condicional extraccion de usuarios (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla de usuarios con la siguiente estructura:

```
| Id | Nombre   | Correo            | Jerarquia                 | Estado |
|----|----------|-------------------|---------------------------|--------|
| 1  | Juan     | juan@mail.com     | Gerencia-Ventas           | 1      |
| 2  | Pedro    | pedro@mail.com    | Gerencia-Ventas-Usuario   | 1      |
| 3  | Alberto  | alberto@mail.com  | Gerencia-Finanzas         | 1      |
| 4  | Fernando | fernando@mail.com | Gerencia-Finanzas-Usuario | 1      |
| 5  | Osvaldo  | osvaldo@mail.com  | Gerencia-Finanzas-Usuario | 1      |
| 6  | Isma     | isma@correo.com   | Gerencia-Ventas-Usuario   | 1      |
```

Tengo una query, la cual, segun la jerarquia que posea el usuario, genera el listado de usuarios segun su departamento:

```
SELECT Id, Nombre, Correo, Jerarquia
FROM usuario
WHERE Estado = 1 and Jerarquia like @jerarquiaUsuario + '%'
```

La variable @jerarquiaUsuario es dinamica y se inyecta desde una aplicacion, ejemplo, si ingresa Alberto, Id 3, @jerarquiaUsuario tendra como valor `Gerencia-Finanzas`, entonces, el podra ver el listado de todos los usuarios que esten bajo esa jerarquia.

Cual es mi consulta? Me solicitaron ahora, que el usuario Juan, con Id 1, aparte de ver todos los usuarios bajo la jerarquia `Gerencia-Ventas`, tambien pueda visualizar dos usuarios mas del area finanzas, que serian Fernando, con Id 4 y Osvaldo con Id 5.

He tratado de hacer la query utilizando un case en la sentencia where, pero no me ha dado resultado en nada.

Espero me puedan ayudar y entender la explicacion.

Comment: Una duda, dime todos los usuarios que puede ver alberto

Comment: Todos los usuarios dentro de la jerarquia **Gerencia-Finanzas**, en este caso, el mismo y los usuarios con Id 4 y 5, por eso la query original tiene `@jerarquiaUsuario + '%'`, que en este caso seria `'Gerencia-Finanzas%'` para Alberto

Comment: Mira, me parece que tu base de datos no está correctamente normalizada, busca en internet que es la normalización de base de datos, para que te lleves una idea general de lo que es y después me avisas a ver como se te ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digamos que tienes un criterio más o menos normalizado de seleccionar los usuarios según `Jerarquia` de un usuario en particular, te diría incluso, para  evitar el uso de `LIKE` que podrías hacer algo así:

```
SELECT Id, Nombre, Correo, Jerarquia
       FROM usuario
       WHERE Estado = 1 
             and LEFT(Jerarquia, LEN(@jerarquiaUsuario)) == @jerarquiaUsuario
```

---

Ahora, llega un jefe o un gerente y te plantea:

> que el usuario Juan, con Id 1, aparte de ver todos los usuarios bajo
> la jerarquia Gerencia-Ventas, tambien pueda visualizar dos usuarios
> mas del area finanzas, que serian Fernando, con Id 4 y Osvaldo con Id
> 5.

En esta instancia deberías repreguntar: **¿A que obedece este cambio? o más bien ¿existe un criterio general para describir esta excepción o simplemente se trata de una excepción?**. En caso de tratarse de una excepción al criterio general, cosa que en principio es lo que parece, podrías resolverlo de forma "hardcoded" así:

```
SELECT Id, Nombre, Correo, Jerarquia
       FROM usuario
       WHERE Estado = 1 
             and (
                  LEFT(Jerarquia, LEN(@jerarquiaUsuario)) == @jerarquiaUsuario
                  OR (@UsuarioId = 1 AND Id IN (4, 5))
             )
```

Claramente necesitarás un `@UsuarioId` es decir el usuario de la consulta en cuestión.  El problema que tiene esto, es que si la organización acepta las excepciones es muy difícil asumir que no existirán otras en un futuro, en cuyo caso lo ideal sería tener una tabla para manejar estas:

```
CREATE TABLE UsuariosVistasAdicionales TABLE (
     Id           INT NOT NULL,
     IdHabilitado INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO UsuariosVistasAdicionales (Id, IdHabilitado)
VALUES (1, 4), (1, 5)
                  
SELECT Id, Nombre, Correo, Jerarquia
       FROM usuario
       WHERE Estado = 1 
             and (
                  LEFT(Jerarquia, LEN(@jerarquiaUsuario)) == @jerarquiaUsuario
                  OR (Id in (SELECT IdHabilitado
                                    FROM UsuariosVistasAdicionales
                                    WHERE Id = @UsuarioId))
             )
```

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias!
Justamente lo que indicas me sirvio. Lo que me solicitaron fue un caso especifico y no algo que se aplicara a todos los usuarios.